# Overlay two sequences of png's and turn them into a movie

Tags: ffmpeg

I've found how to turn a png sequence into a movie and I've found how to overlay two movies using transparency but I don't know how to do both things at once (using png's transparency).

The bottom layer of png's is smaller than the top one and needs to be stretched to a certain resolution and also have a padding to be centered.

The output doesn't have to have alpha (black for alpha is ok). I'm a bit confused by the abundance of filter options.

For the moment I've found:

```
./ffmpeg -i ./seq1/%d.bmp -vf "movie=./%d.png [a]; [in][a] overlay=0:366" combined.m2v
```

It works, now I've got to find the padding and resize things

Comment: This might be a more appropriate question for [Video Production Stack Exchange](http://video.stackexchange.com/). Perhaps [this question](http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/10640/ffmpeg-overlaying-and-blending-videos) can help even.